# Did Mickey Mouse ever face off against sky pirates in an official comic?

Tags: story-identification, comics, mickey-mouse

I recall many years ago reading a Mickey Mouse comic in which Mickey flew an airplane and fought against other characters, such as Pete, in other airplanes. This was not the bootleg black-and-white "Air Pirates" comic, as I distinctly remember the comic was drawn in color, and had a much cleaner drawing style, so it couldn't have been from the 1930s. Does anyone know the name of this comic?

Comment: Mickey Mouse comics are still published in many countries, so more details are needed to identify the story you are looking for. How many years are _"many"_? 5? 10? 50? What language was the comic written in? What country where you in? Do you remember anything about the "Sky Pirates"? Is the setting realistic (modern planes), steampunk (retro-futuristic flying machines), fantasy (flying ships), sci-fi, ....?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds a lot like Floyd Gottfredson's The Mail Pilot. It has Mickey and several other mail pilots fighting Pete and his air pirates (I could only find German pages from 2003)

[image: The Mail Pilot 1 German][1](https://inducks.org/s.php?c=YM+017)
[image: The Mail Pilot 2 German][1](https://inducks.org/s.php?c=YM+017)
[image: The Mail Pilot 3 German][1](https://inducks.org/s.php?c=YM+017)

While this comic is from the 30s, the colouring send to be much newer.

Comment: Available in English here; https://archive.org/details/waltdisneysperil0000krei/page/n1/mode/2up

Comment: [Inducks link](https://inducks.org/s.php?c=YM+017).